# Difference between Spark toLocalIterator and iterator methods

Tags: java, foreach, iterator, apache-spark

While coding the Spark programs i came across this `toLocalIterator()` method. As earlier i was using only `iterator()` method.

If anyone has ever used this method please throw some lights.

I came across while using `foreach` and `foreachPartition` methods in Spark program.

Can I pass the `foreach` method result to `toLocalIterator` method or vice verse.

```
toLocalIterator() -> foreachPartition()
iterator() -> foreach()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, the `iterator` method from an RDD should not be called. As you can read in the [Javadocs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#iterator(org.apache.spark.Partition, org.apache.spark.TaskContext)): *This should ''not'' be called by users directly, but is available for implementors of custom subclasses of RDD.*

As for the `toLocalIterator`, it is used to collect the data from the RDD scattered around your cluster into one only node, the one from which the program is running, and do something with all the data in the same node. It is similar to the `collect` method, but instead of returning a `List` it will return an `Iterator`.

`foreach` is used to apply a function to each of the elements of the RDD, while `foreachPartition` is to apply a function to each of the partitions. In the first approach you get one element at a time (to parallelize more) and in the second one you get the whole partition (if you need to perform an operation with all the data).

So yes, after applying a function to an RDD using `foreach` or `foreachPartition` you can call `toLocalIterator` to get an iterator with all the contents of the RDD and process it. However, bear in mind that if your RDD is very big, you may have memory issues. If you want to transform it to an RDD again after doing the operations you need, use the `SparkContext` to parallelize it again.